# Errors during the installation of ucl in MacOS Mojave

Tags: python, pip

I have problem with install on MacOS Mojave.
I need a ucl library in my project. I do not know about python. I need to run the ready code once.
When I try:

```
MBP-ukasz:psCMS2 lukasz$ sudo pip install ucl
```

I have error:

```
The directory '/Users/lukasz/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/lukasz/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting ucl
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/53/a5/fedfc8af32519d2fb172736b7b101239004ae30bdcc036a7c1fdeb152927/ucl-0.8.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: ucl
  Running setup.py install for ucl ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-DBLg7v/ucl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-huMBs9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'ucl' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/src
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/uclmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-intel-2.7/src/uclmodule.o
    src/uclmodule.c:2:10: fatal error: 'ucl.h' file not found
    #include <ucl.h>
             ^~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-DBLg7v/ucl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-huMBs9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-DBLg7v/ucl/
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: `brew install ucl`, then `CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ucl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ucl/lib" pip install ucl`.

Comment: it's not working.

Comment: [ucl](https://pypi.org/project/ucl/) is a Python wrapper for [libucl](https://github.com/vstakhov/libucl/) so you need to install `libucl` first.